# Gimp/Mac: Text tool interprets keystrokes as commands

Tags: macos, gimp

I wonder if you can help me with this rather bizarre phenomenon.
I'm using Gimp 2.8.3 on a Mac OS 10.9.5 and I try to insert text with the Text Tool. Easy enough, but when I type e.g. "Jazz", I get as far as "J", and then the "a" is interpreted as command and the airbrush tool gets activated. This happens with every (lowercase) key which in principle has a command function.

I checked the manual but there's no mention of something that needs to be switched off to use the text entry tool.

Anybody seen this before?

Thanks, Rob

Update: I've had the brilliant idea to check for Gimp updates. Turned out, there's a Gimp 2.8.14 now, which doesn't show this behaviour anymore. So, it seems to have been a bug in Gimp which luckily has been fixed.

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have a keyboard key stuck? I'd suggest unplugging and re-plugging it back in, or doing a quick keyboard mash. I'm curious if what you're seeing is part of a keyboard shortcut (e.g. ALT+key or similar).

Comment: @trnelson: Solved the problem by upgrading to newer Gimp ... The keys haven't been the problem, I think it was a genuine bug. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Rob, glad to hear it! That's a strange bug. Do you know if it's been submitted as an issue to the Gimp team? If you were using an older version it may not be a big deal, but if it's a fairly recent one you may want to let them know.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: if anyone is hit by this or a similar bug, there is a workaround if upgrading/fix is not an option: gimp 2.8, the old off-image text editor for creating text can be used, by checking the `Use editor` control in the text tool options.

GIMP will them pop a small blank window where the text can be typed without being intercepted by other parts of the application.